# Marketing Cloud - default no. of digit for phone no. field and default currency

Tags: marketing-cloud, currency, phone

Default max max number of digits for phone number field in my marketing cloud is 9. How can I change it?

Similarly, if I try to add a facebook (?) account, it doesn't accept the account whose currency is in INR (Indian Rupee). How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

The field size for Phone Data Extension field is 50 characters:

[image: Phone field type]

Hence I don't recognise the limitation of 9 characters you mention. Be aware, that phone numbers should be stored with country code + phone number. E.g. for DK country code is +45 and the phone numbers are 8 digits. Hence it should be stored in following way: 4512345678 which I have done before, and never faced the 9 digit limit.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Actually I have created a data extension (with a phone no. field) and trying to create a record in it. If I enter a phone no. of 10 digit starting with any digit except 1, it gives error 'review your data and ensure the validity of all provided values.' while saving, however If I start the number with 1, it allows me to save the record with 10 digit number.

Comment: Is this a Shared Data Extension? In that case, you might be seeing the issue described here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gY4QAI

Comment: No, it's not shared extension.